# This file can not be opened as a file description , it is probably compressed

Tags: android, audio, andengine, soundpool

I am developing one game application.Using SourdFactory I am playing sound. I open some files multiple times but and sound is also plays.But some time it gives me following warning does not load the file

> 12-30 20:47:24.890: W/System.err(27969):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file
>   descriptor; it is probably compressed 12-30 20:47:24.890:
>   W/System.err(27969):  at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method) 12-30
>   20:47:24.890: W/System.err(27969):    at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:331) 12-30
>   20:47:24.890: W/System.err(27969):    at
>   org.andengine.audio.sound.SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(SoundFactory.java:74)
>   12-30 20:47:24.890: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.numberGameScene.loadSound(numberGameScene.java:445)
>   12-30 20:47:24.890: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.numberGameScene.loadResources(numberGameScene.java:202)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.ManageableScene.(ManageableScene.java:26)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.numberGameScene.(numberGameScene.java:140)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.SceneManager.setCurrentScene(SceneManager.java:158)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.PlaySceneActivity.chageScenne(PlaySceneActivity.java:801)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.pairGameScene.changeScene(pairGameScene.java:1991)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   com.witsindia.benandbella.pairGameScene$17$1.run(pairGameScene.java:1912)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 12-30
>   20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   12-30 20:47:24.895: W/System.err(27969):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)